# Nested forms regarding association belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-forms, fields-for

I have the classes `Person` and `Fingerprint` and I want to work with nested forms in order to fill Fingerprint's attributes.

The implementation is as follows:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fingerprint
end

class Fingerprint < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**Person's controller:**

```
def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    @person.build_fingerprint

    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
      ....
end

def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:name, fingerprints_attributes: [:fingertips_category])
end
```

**Person's form:**

```
%= form_with(model: person) do |form| %>
...

  <div>
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_area :name %>
  </div>
    <%= form.fields_for :fingerprint do |fingerprint_form| %>
    <%= fingerprint_form.label :fingertips_category %>
    <%= fingerprint_form.text_field :fingertips_category %>
    <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, I don't get how to initialize the `Fingerprint's attributes` with the help of `build_fingerprint` method.

Comment: I believe semantically even one-fingered person not `belongs_to`, but `has_one :fingerprint`

Comment: Assuming OP only has one finger, I think you're both very mean forcing additional typing on their part with these comments.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing about it being a `belongs_to` association that means you can't use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :fingerprint` just like a `has_*` association.

Only thing is that you need `fingerprint_attributes` (not `fingerprints...` plural) in your `permit` call. So then in the `create` you'd just have the `@person = Person.new(person_params)` and then `@person.save`. You haven't shown it here but in your `new` action you would need to instantiate the `fingerprint` in the `@person` record you're using in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I've figured out some useful links for all those people who are struggling with nested forms regarding `belongs_to`.

As smathy mentioned, it's not possible to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with `belongs_to`.
And actually, you would have to take a circuitous way to reach that goal with `belongs_to`.
So, I will work with `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/nested-has-one-object-should-be-built-automatically-when-nessecary/75271/4

Edit: I forgot to give the solution regarding belongs_to:

```
class Fingerprint < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :fingerprint

 def fingerprint_attributes=(fingerprint_attributes)
    self.fingerprint = Fingerprint.new
    fingerprint_attributes.each do |i, fingerprint_attribute|
      self.fingerprint.fingertips_category = fingerprint_attribute
    end  
  end

end
```

**Person's controller:**

```
 def new
    @person = Person.new
    @person.build_fingerprint  
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.new(person_params)
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if @person.save
        ...
      end
    end
  end

def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, fingerprint_attributes: [:fingertips_category])
    end
```

**Person's _form.thml.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: person) do |form| %>
...

  <div>
    <%= form.label :name, style: "display: block" %>
    <%= form.text_area :name %>
  </div>
    <%= form.fields_for :fingerprint do |fingerprint_form| %>
    <%= fingerprint_form.label :fingertips_category %>
    <%= fingerprint_form.text_field :fingertips_category %>
    <% end %>
  <div>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```